# Can text and an image be merged to become a single image in Livecode

Tags: livecode

I need to be able to take some variable text entered by the user and merge it with a "template" image to create a single image as PNG (or other). Can this be done with Livecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One way is to create a transparent field on top (or in front) of an image and group them. Give this group the name "Caption". Then use this script:

```
export snapshot from group "Caption" to myPictureData as PNG
```

Now you can create a new image and set the text of the image to myPictureData or save myPictureData to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an image in your stack, the import snapshot command is a great option:

```
import snapshot from group "imgAndFld" with effects
```

The optional 'with effects' clause will preserve any graphic effects you have applied to the imported objects, important if you want your text to have a drop shadow or glow effect, for example.